# How to determine number of values added to vector in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, cin

I'm trying to build a little task using C++ in which I need to allow the user to determine up front how many gross_paychecks they would like to place in a vector called 'gross_paychecks_vector'.

So far this is what I have:

```
vector<double> gross_paychecks_vector (5);
  double gross_paychecks;
  // Add 5 doubles to vector
  cout << "Please enter an integer" << endl;
  cin >> gross_paychecks;
  for(gross_paychecks = 0; gross_paychecks <= gross_paychecks_vector; ++gross_paychecks ){
    cin >> gross_paychecks;
  }
```

Right now I'm somewhat lost because I'm not sure whether to switch the vector to something like `vector<double> gross_paychecks {}` because it throws an error in the for loop.

Also I'm not sure how to go with the for loop (should I actually use a for-loop or something else?). I need to accept input from the user as long as it has not met the numbers of gross_paychecks that he/she has specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
vector<double> gross_paychecks_vector;   // initially the vector is empty
...
  cout << "How many paychecks:" << endl;
  cin >> gross_paychecks;

  for (int i = 0; i < gross_paychecks; i++)
  {
    double value;
    cin >> value;
    gross_paychecks_vector.push_back(value);  // add new value to vector
  }

  // display values in vector
  for (auto & value : gross_paychecks_vector)
  {
     cout << value << "\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Additionally. If you want to use modern C++ features, you would use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> grossPaychecks{};

    std::cout << "How many paychecks:\n";
    size_t numberOfPaychecks{0};
    std::cin >> numberOfPaychecks;

    // Read all data
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin),numberOfPaychecks, std::back_inserter(grossPaychecks));

    // Print all data
    std::copy(grossPaychecks.begin(), grossPaychecks.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```